# Initialising javascript variable in Razor template (cshtml) and changing style in runtime - is it bad practice?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Note: the following code was just a 5 minute idea to be used as starting point, not a final solution**

Recently I proposed an idea to change the CSS of an element by taking URL for the background from web.config (the CSS class myclass was applied to some divs which need this feature)

```
 <script>
    var bgUrl = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BackgroundUrl"]';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myclass').css('background-image', 'url("' + bgUrl + '")');
    });
</script>
```

This is very wire-frame kind of solution and code could be moved to seperate file, use "data-" attribute to store image names etc.

But the other developer in the team says it's bad practice because:

1. it allows the use of Server elements inside client scripts.
2. It is intended for in-line scripting / styling which is bad practice.

In-line scripting can be handled in final solution but other concerns got me concerned.

Thanks in advance.

Vijay

Comment: You can use a ViewBag or something like that...are you working with C# or VB ?

Comment: C# .The rest of the style for the divs has to come from CSS except the background image URL.

Comment: Try this on the method that return your view: `ViewBag.MyBackPic = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BackgroundUrl"].ToString(); ` and in your View: `var bgUrl = '@ViewBag.MyBackPic';`

Comment: What about changing the style (setting background image URL)? Is it acceptable or not? Thanks.

Comment: If it is in the AppSettings it is more easy to change the route of the image, just changing the value on the web.config

Comment: Sorry, should have explained earlier. Please see my reply to Jason (below).

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to keep less server side code in razor views. my personal opinion is, view should be purely for markup(*in the new version of MVC(MVC6), we have tag helpers which is more HTMLish than the Html helper methods.*). Add only absolutely necessary razor/C# code to views.

With your current approach, what if tomorrow you want to switch the background image of another element in your page? Do you want to add another C# statement/line to read from the config again and use that ? This does not look good.

It is a good idea to keep your styling in your css files. Since you want to switch it, you should consider supporting some sort of theming. You can keep an entry in your configuration to determine which theme/css file to use.

Here is a very simple (*can be improved*) solution.

Create css file(s) for each theme you want inside your `~/Contents` filder

***ThemeGreen.css file***

```
.myclass
{
   color:green;
   background: url('SomeImageName.png') no-repeat !important;
}
```

***ThemeRed.css file***

```
.myclass
{
   color:red;
   background: url('SomeImageNameRed.png') no-repeat !important;
}
```

And you can write an action filter to get the current theme to use that to build the correct name/path of the css file you want to use.

```
public class MyThemePicker : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var themeCssName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Theme"] as string;
        var vb = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;
        vb.ThemeCssName = themeCssName;
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Assuming you have an AppSettings entry called Theme.

```
<appSettings>   
    <add key="Theme" value="GreenSite"/>
</appSettings>
```

And you register it in your `ApplicationStart` event so it is available for all requests.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{      
    //Existing code goes here

    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyThemePicker ());
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    //Existing code goes here
}
```

Now in your layout, you will load the css file for the current theme.

```
<head>
  <link href="~/Content/@(ViewBag.ThemeCssName).css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="myclass">Some div with themed css</div>
  @RenderBody()
</body>
```

You can create multiple theme folder and use that if you want. In that case, Instead of the file name, you will get the directory name when building the css path.

Comment: Theming was in my mind too but it is too late to make a big change in the project. Might be a possibility in next phase. This was a quick solution for only one div in the page.

Comment: Just add a bit more - the above code was just a 5 minute job and not supposed to be final solution. For making it generic, "data-" attribute would be used store image names, taking URL from some configuration source, along with moving JS code to separate file. The idea was presented to show the feasibility of making code more configurable without re-writing any code at all once the binaries have been produced and locked. Your solution also does not satisfy the requirement of building once and deploying multiple times where target environment is not known fore-hand.

Comment: Yes. When you want to change to a new image/style , create a new Css file and update your config to use that. You do not need to recompile.

Comment: Ah! I get it, did not read some part of your code correctly. But we want to lock down binaries and no new CSS can go in. That would be seen as code change.

Comment: Then you should consider storing your theme related stuff  in a db table and read that in the app start and use that.

Comment: Thanks but that is not going to be accepted either.

Answer (score 1):

It's typically recommended to avoid inline styles. That's not to say they should be avoided at all costs. Look at any of the JS UI library controls. All of them have some level of inline styling.

The bigger design question I have is why a background image file name is stored in app settings? you now have to manually keep 2 independent artifacts synchronized.

Understanding the larger picture will give you context to what the preferred solution would be.

Comment: Thanks Jason. The larger picture is - the images will be stored in CDN  (at a different location from the rest of the app) and the application will use different backgrounds in different environments. Currently the URL is in CSS file (compiled from LESS). So for deploying app in different environments it requires a re-build. With something like above, the path can be poked during deployment and get the job done.

Comment: in that case I would look at a themed solution. Similar to jQuery UI themes. the styling for each environment is static. At run-time, or build-time, determine which theme to reference in the master layout. Views don't need knowledge or logic to override style.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but is above solution strictly a no-no? Apart from alternative, I want to know what's wrong in the solution I proposed.

Comment: there are very few, if any, absolutes. My personal opinion is this may be a result of brainstorming, but it's not a valid solution to the problem.

Comment: This was supposed to be a starting point of brain-storming and made more generic before arriving at a final solution. A 5 minute snippet was just to present the idea of making it configurable to allow deployment of same binaries in environments which are not know fore-hand. Try seeing it from release team's point of view which has to create multiple environments (a couple every month, and we have 80+ environments as I write this, with more coming up) and this application will be deployed in each environment but will not be re-built.